# C linked list gets modified when passed by pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to figure out why is my linked list modfied in the following program structure:

```
void edit(NODE pHead)
{
    /* Why is this modifying my list ?? */
    pHead->data = 1337;
}

void call(NODE *pHead)
{
    NODE pFirst = *pHead;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        edit(*pHead);
        *pHead = (*pHead)->next;
    }

    *pHead = pFirst;
    printList(*pHead);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* A simple list */
    NODE pList = NULL;

    /* The number of nodes */
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /* Init list */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //Read values.
        int timestamp;
        float data;
        scanf("%d%f", &timestamp, &data);

        //Add node.
        addLastNode(&pList, timestamp, data);
    }

    printList(pList);

    call(&pList);

    return 0;
}
```

I simply don't understand this. Isn't the edit function supposed to create a local copy of my linked list? 
When printing my final list, the output is the modified list, instead of the original one.Can someone explain to me what is wrong? Also here is my list structure:

```
/* A structure representing the node of a list */
typedef struct LIST
{
    int timestamp;
    float data;
    struct LIST *next;
} * NODE;
```

Comment: You are passing the pointer by value. Yes, you are using a copy of that pointer variable. But it still points to an element of your list which will be modified.

Comment: You passed in a pointer by value. A copy of the *pointer* is created. The pointer contains nothing more than an address. Once inside your `edit` function you dereference that address and set data to the members that reside there. That's quite-literally all your `edit` member does. If you want a copy of your linked list you'll have to write the code to make one (and here are *millions* of examples on how to do so online).

Comment: @WhozCraig Then what is the difference between passing the list as NODE * and NODE ? If it gets modified both ways?

Comment: Both pass by value; the difference is *what* the value represents actually *is*. One is the value of a pointer to pointer; the other the value of a pointer. Some time in a good text on the C programming language is probably on the horizon. And I *firmly* second @CataCata on that; hiding pointer types in typedefs is rarely helpful. There are really only two patterns that warrant it, and neither are in your code. Don't.

Comment: @bruno So by passing the list as a NODE, I can still access and modify the values inside that node, but I can't modify the node itself ? Is that correct ?

Comment: What do you mean you can't modify the node itself? what do you refer to as the `node itself`?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue The address of the node. ~Bruno Well, the rest of the code is a basic implementation of a linked list, like adding a node from the right and printing a list. Nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the edit function supposed to create a local copy of my linked list?

having

> ```
> void edit(NODE pHead)
> {
>      /* Why is this modifying my list ?? */
>      pHead->data = 1337;
>  }
> ```

and

> ```
> typedef struct LIST
> {
>     int timestamp;
>     float data;
>     struct LIST *next;
>  } * NODE;
> ```

*NODE* is **pointer** to a *LIST*, so in *edit* the cell is *not* a copy, and when you modify it the modification is not only local

It is exactly like that :

```
void edit(struct LIST * pHead)
{
     /* Why is this modifying my list ?? */
     pHead->data = 1337;
 }
```

this is the difference with :

```
 void edit(struct LIST pHead)
 {
     pHead.data = 1337;
 }
```

where the cell is local and the modification has no impact outside

This is why **never use a typedef to hide a pointer** because that let you supposing you manipulate a value while you manipulate a pointer